# How to repair cdedit program?

Tags: windows-7

`cdedit.exe` will not start. When I double click, it flashes on screen for a split second and does not load.

I have Windows 7. I am unable to change my default operating system.

Comment: Is this a new install, or has it been installed for a while?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- open a command prompt (press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> then type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- now type `cdedit.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- If `cdedit.exe` can't be found, browse to the appropriate directory (where `cdedit.exe` is, and run it from there).

You should be able to see any error message displayed on screen, that you wouldn't otherwise see, with this method.

Comment: Wayne seems to have a problem running the program; not finding it.

Comment: I am trying to help him troubleshoot the problem. But maybe *Windows* wont find the path for it in the command line (especially if it's not somewhere in `%path%`). So I am unsure what your comment is adding.

Comment: Not to mention that the program could output some error logs in the CLI that might help us to troubleshoot.